# Matlab - How to process images to recognize a digit?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, artificial-intelligence

Hi I am new to AI and MATLAB. I want to find another way of processing image files. The purpose of this is to differentiate the digit '4' from other digits. The below code is one way (a basic way) of processing images. It takes the images, converts it to a matrix and ignores the black pixels around the edges so it focuses only on the pixels with variation (the white pixels).

```
% 3. convert the images into a 2D matrix
train_params = reshape(train_images, size(train_images, 1) * size(train_images, 2), size(train_images, 3));

% 4. measure the variance of the different pixels and discard those which
% are zero
train_stds = std(train_params');
tokeep = find(train_stds>0);
train_params = train_params(tokeep,:);
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDzWp.png) is the images which are being processed:

I want to find another (more focused) way of processing these images to recognize the number '4'.

Thank you

Comment: Read this: https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/digit-classification-using-hog-features.html

Comment: Here's another function that may be pertinent: https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/ocr.html and another example of a deep learning based approach for digit classification: https://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/examples/create-simple-deep-learning-network-for-classification.html

Answer (score 1):

You are new to Matlab and it is understandable, but I think you should go deep to image processing concepts first. We have so many recognition methods in image processing to solve your problem. Please take a look at [here](https://it.mathworks.com/discovery/image-recognition.html). Even you can recognize a digit by simple [morphology](https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/dilate.htm) operations in Matlab or by complicated machine learning approach. You can find a method [here](http://www.vincentchu.com/digitrecognition.html) which solves this problem with Neural network. And also Matlab tutorial @Sardar Usama already introduced is one of the best which uses  HOG features and a multiclass SVM classifier to classify digits. You can find more [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/?term=tag:%22lpr%22).